# Can draconic Strike be used to damage objects?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, monk, unarmed-combat

Under [Monk of the Way of the Ascendant Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheAscendantDragon), the Draconic Strike ability says:

> When you damage a target with an unarmed strike, you can change the damage type to acid, cold, fire, lightning, or poison.

Can a target be an object?

Answer (score 7):

#### Yes, you can target an object with an attack.

In the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack) we can find what are the feasible targets for attacks:

> **1. Choose a target.** Pick a target within your attack's range: a creature, an object, or a location
>
> **2. Determine modifiers.** [...]
>
> **3. Resolve the attack.** [...]

These are the [same](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#MakinganAttack) in the Player's Handbook.

You may wonder what the target's AC is, when your are trying to hit an object: indeed, in this case you have to make an attack roll and compare it with an AC (see [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#AttackRolls) for the rules about attack rolls and resolving attacks).

In the basic rules (and also in the Dungeon Master Guide, page 246) you can find the guidelines for the [Statistics of Objects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/running-the-game#StatisticsforObjects), with examples of AC and HPs of some type of objects.

A robust wooden chest, for example, has an AC 15 and 10 HPs.

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes

The rules for making an attack state:

> Pick a **target** within your attack’s range: a creature, **an object**, or a location.